# How to handle products URL's when exporting/importing products into Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, importexport, seo, migration

I have a small shop (less than 300 products) on Magento 1.7.2 and I want to move to Magento 2.

Since I dont have many products, I think it would be easier to export the products (using CSV files) and importing them into the new Magento 2 installation than using the Data Migration Tool (which still has many bugs).

I'd like to know whether doing this (exporting/importing) will keep the original products URL's in the new Magento 2 installation since I receive good search traffic for some niche products that I wouldn't like to lose because of URL changes.

Comment: I've sucessfully moved my store to Magento 2 through exporting/importing. I made sure that the URL's stay the same in the CSV files, so there is no problem doing it this way and search traffic wont be affected.